# Button or other form elements + onclick element won't work on pages unless on index.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I have some PNG images that should be clickable (ex.`onclick="changeCamera()"`).

They work fine as long as I put them in the index.php page, but this element (or others like buttons and input fields) just won't work on my other pages where I need them to work.

I'm only using the index.php page as the "home" page, and all the rest of my pages open with `<?php include(pagina($_GET['pagina'])); ?>` in the `<SECTION>` part. I don't know PHP, it's something that I copied from a previous project.

This is my index page where the buttons work just fine:

```
<?php
include("inc/inc_pagina.php");
if(!isset($_GET['pagina'])){
    $_GET['pagina'] = "home";
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> test site </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Test website">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/buttons.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1> test1</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul id="main-menu">
            <li><a href="index.php?pagina=home" target="_self">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?pagina=test">Testpagina</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="http://validator.w3.org/">w3c validator</a></li> -->
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <br ><br ><br ><br ><br ><br >
    <img src="images/alert2.png" id="alert" onclick="changeAlert()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px">
        <img src="images/na2.png" id="na" onclick="changeNa()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px">
        <img src="images/checked2.png" id="checked" onclick="changeChecked()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px">
        <img src="images/error2.png" id="error" onclick="changeError()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px">
        <img src="images/comment2.png" id="comment" onclick="changeComment()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="22px" height="22px">
        <img src="images/camera2.png" id="camera" onclick="changeCamera()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px">
    <section>
        <?php include(pagina($_GET['pagina'])); ?>
    </section>
    <footer>Copyright © 2019
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my test page where nothing seems to work, and nothing is even clickable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/buttons.js"></script>
<img src="images/alert2.png" id="alert" onclick="changeAlert()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px"/></br>
<img src="images/na2.png" id="na" onclick="changeNa()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px"></br>
<img src="images/checked2.png" id="checked" onclick="changeChecked()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px"></br>
<img src="images/error2.png" id="error" onclick="changeError()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px"></br>
<img src="images/comment2.png" id="comment" onclick="changeComment()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="22px" height="22px"></br>
<img src="images/camera2.png" id="camera" onclick="changeCamera()" style="cursor:pointer;" width="25px" height="25px"></br>
```

Comment: is your `test` page in the same directory as your `index` page? I ask because `javascript/buttons.js` is relative to a directory rather than the site root

Comment: console.log() ouput any error?? the scope is in diferent files you need `window.changeCamera()`

Comment: The test page is indeed in the same directory as the index page..

Comment: Walter, the window. part doesn't help here neighter..
I have other projects where i worked with the same code where it's still work, so don't quit understand what's wrong here..

Comment: Ok so i managed to find the issue by my self..
The issue was that the section part defined as position:relative; in the css, once this was deleted everything works fine!